# Check if status is Paid and display content accordingly

Tags: python, django

I would like to know who i can check if a post item has been paid or not and display the content accordingly for the fields content and content_preview.

models.py

```
...
```

views.py

```
...
```

But if i manually set a post to paid nothing changes at my template and i was not yet able to find the issue

template.html

```
   ...
```

i guess my problem is that i dont know how to call the status at the if statment on my template. Currently it always displays the paid status and its content instead of the content preview if no paid record exsists

thankful for any hint

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div>
            {% if post.get_STATUS_display|lower == 'paid' %}
                <p>{{ post.content|safe|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            {% else %}
                <p>{{ post.content_preview|safe|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your queryset is correct? You're querying `Post_Sell_Multiple` instead of `Post_Paid_Sell_Multiple`

Comment: `post = get_object_or_404(Post_Sell_Multiple, pk=pk)` shouldn't be `post = get_object_or_404(Post_Paid_Sell_Multiple, pk=pk)` ?

Comment: I dont think so, i want to display the Post and not the status on the details page.
beside i tried that and it makes no difference at all or in other word i run into 404.

Comment: Can you post your Post_Sell_Multiple model? Without seeing everything is hard to see the relationship between them

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
{% if post.STATUS == 1 %} <<<<<<
```

---

Alternatively, you might find it convenient to define some additional variable such as

```
UNPAID_STATUS = 0
PAID_STATUS = 1

POST_PAYMENT_STATUS = (
(UNPAID_STATUS, 'unpaid'),
(PAID_STATUS, 'paid)
)
```

then do

```
{% if post.STATUS == post.PAID_SATUS %}
```

Comment: Do you have some unpaid entries, and also kept the rest of your code including the `else` part?

Comment: I simply created a new sell multiple object and added the paid status at DjangoAdmin. But it always shows the Paid content